# Tokenize program in C

Tags: c

For my computer science class I have to come up with program to tokenize strings for a given input file using the maximal munch algorithm. This is what my friend and I have done so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

FILE *
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if(argc = 1)
    {
        return stdin;
    } 
    else
    {
        return fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);

    if(src == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int c, nc;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF || (c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t')
        {
            printf("Blank Space");
        }
        else if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^')
        {
            if(c == '+')
            {
                printf("%s \t addition operator\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == '-')
            {
                printf("%s \t subtraction operator\n", c);
            }  
            else if(c == '*')
            {
                printf("%s \t multiplication operator\n", c);
            }
            if(c == '/')
            {
                printf("%s \t division operator\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == '^')
            {
                printf("%s \t exponentiation\n", c);
            }
        }
        else if(c == '(' || c == ')')
        {
            if(c == '(')
            {
                printf("%s \t open parentheses\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == ')')
            {
                printf("%s \t close parentheses\n", c);
            }
        }
        else if(c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '=')
        {
            if(c == '<' && (nc = getchar()) == '=')
            {
                printf("%s%s \t comparison operator\n", c, nc);
            }
            else if(c == '>' && (nc = getchar()) == '=')
            {
                printf("%s%s \t comparison operator\n", c, nc);
            }
            else if(c == '>' || c == '<')
            {
                printf("%s \t comparison operator\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == '=')
            {
                printf("%s \t equals operator\n", c);
            }
        }
        else if(isdigit(c))
        {
            printf("%s \t simple numeral \n", c);
        }
        else if(isalpha(c))
        {
            printf("%s \t invalid token\n", c);
        }
    }
}
```

When we compile the program we get the following warning:

> format argument is not a pointer (arg 2).

Comment: 0) `argc = 1` --> `argc == 1`

Comment: 1)`printf("%s \t addition operator\n", c);` --> `printf("%c \t addition operator\n", c);`

Comment: Note that the code which reads `nc = getchar()` runs you into trouble if the user write `if (i>j)` because `nc` reads the `j` and it is then lost completely.

Answer (score 1):

One pretty smart trick to more easily spot the (argc = 1) instead of (argc == 1) kind of mistake is to actually get used to put the constant on the left hand side.
If you had written if (1 = argc), the compiler would have complained saying you were trying to assign a value to a constant, and you would instantly spot that.
This comes from the gnu coding style by the way.

Comment: Personally, I dislike that way of writing code, but I accept that it can help you while you're learning the language and liable to make mistakes like that.  I use compiler warnings that warn about assignments in conditions.  If I truly wanted the assignment, I'd write `if ((argc = 1) != 0)` (which goes to emphasize that in this case, the test is pointless).  Some people prefer `if ((argc = 1))`; I consider that too subtle.

Comment: The way I compile code, it (`if (m = 1) return 2;`) won't compile — it will generate an error (I use GCC with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and some extra options; `-Wall -Werror` is sufficient for this).  I make sure the compiler reports such problems because the compilers I use are capable of doing so.

Comment: Oh I see, but that's not standard, is it ?

Comment: No (not every compiler is obliged to have such fussy options), but the compiler I use for development is set to excruciatingly fussy, so that such problems are not in the code on the development machine.  And when the code is copied to some other machine, the problems are not in the code there either.  So it becomes a non-problem.  If your compiler doesn't have the warnings available, you may decide you need to write the code with the cack-handed logic, but it reads most peculiarly.  I'm not comparing 1; I'm comparing `m` with something (that happens to be `1`).

Comment: I am convinced. Indeed -Wall generates such warnings.

Comment: There is a body of received wisdom that you should write the cack-handed code.  I don't agree with said received wisdom.  You'll find other people who do agree with it, and others who agree with me.  I'm not sure of the relative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on an earlier comment, your block of code comparing `<`, `>` and `=` is susceptible to error and will never match `<=` or `>=` as written. As part of your routine, you are reading `c` twice at the beginning of your `while` loop. Forcing the read of two characters, you will never have `nc` read `=` in `<=` because the second character has already been consumed:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF || (c = getchar()) != '\n')
```

While the intent may be to strip the newline from the input buffer, the effect is to prevent any character from remaining for `nc` to read. A better way to structure the beginning of the loop may be:

```
while (1)
{
    c = fgetc (src);
    if (c == 'q' || c == EOF)    /* just `q` for quit :) */
        break;
    ...
```

In addition to this read issue, if the user enters anything other than `<=` or `>=` you always report `comparison operator`. Take for example `<h`, you check `c` for `<` or `>` and then read `nc` (in this case `h`). While `nc` does not match `=`, the very next condition is satisfied:

```
 else if(c == '>' || c == '<')
```

This results in your code outputting `comparison operator` no matter what the character following the `>` or `<` sign was. A little rewrite of the logic could prevent the error. For example change:

```
    else if(c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '=')
    {
        ...
    }
```

to:

```
    else if ( c == '=')
    {
        printf("\t %c \t equals operator\n", c);
    }
    else if(c == '<' || c == '>')
    {
        if ((nc = fgetc (src)) == '=')
        {
            if(c == '<')
            {
                printf("\t %c= \t comparison equivalence operator\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == '>')
            {
                printf("\t %c= \t comparison equivalence operator\n", c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t %c \t comparison operator\n", c);
            ungetc (nc, src);  /* the next character may be important */
        }
    }
```

Next, if you noticed the use of `fgetc` above, it is important. At the beginning of your code you want to use either `stdin` or a file for input. However, throughout your code you have used `getchar()` for reading the character. This will **not** work if the user supplies a filename as the first argument. You may open the file, but you will be left with a blinking cursor waiting for input on `stdin`. If you intend to have the option of reading from a file, you need to change each:

```
 getchar()
```

to

```
fgetc (src)
```

Lastly, and this is just a pet peeve. I you are asking the user for input, give the user a prompt so they know they are supposed to do something and are not just left wondering if the program is hung. (a simple `input:` is fine). Since you have structured the program to read from either `stdin` or a file, it may not be apparent how to only prompt in the case the program is reading from `stdin` (no prompt is wanted or needed when reading from a file). The solution is to simply pass a pointer to a flag as an argument to your `input_from_args` function. You function sets the flag if reading from `stdin` or leaves it `0` if reading from a file. That allows you to provide a prompt as follows:

```
if (stdf) printf (" input : ");   /* stdf being the stdinflag */
```

Putting it all together, an updated version of the code that reads from either a file or `stdin` could be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

FILE *
input_from_args (int argc, const char *argv[], size_t *stdinflag)
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        *stdinflag = 1;
        return stdin;
    } 
    else
    {
        *stdinflag = 0;
        return fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char **argv)
{
    size_t stdf = 0;
    FILE *src = input_from_args (argc, argv, &stdf);

    if(src == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int c = 0;
    int nc = 0;
    int strip = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if (stdf) printf (" input : ");
        c = fgetc (src);

        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t')
        {
            printf("\t    Blank Space\n");
        }
        else if(c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^')
        {
            if(c == '+')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t addition operator\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == '-')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t subtraction operator\n", c);
            }  
            else if(c == '*')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t multiplication operator\n", c);
            }
            if(c == '/')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t division operator\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == '^')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t exponentiation\n", c);
            }
        }
        else if(c == '(' || c == ')')
        {
            if(c == '(')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t open parentheses\n", c);
            }
            else if(c == ')')
            {
                printf("\t %c \t close parentheses\n", c);
            }
        }
        else if ( c == '=')
        {
            printf("\t %c \t equals operator\n", c);
        }
        else if(c == '<' || c == '>')
        {
            if ((nc = fgetc (src)) == '=')
            {
                if(c == '<')
                {
                    printf("\t %c= \t comparison equivalence operator\n", c);
                }
                else if(c == '>')
                {
                    printf("\t %c= \t comparison equivalence operator\n", c);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\t %c \t comparison operator\n", c);
                ungetc (nc, src);
            }
        }
        else if(isdigit(c))
        {
            printf("\t %c \t simple numeral \n", c);
        }
        else if(isalpha(c))
        {
            if (tolower (c) == 'q')
            {
                printf ("\t\n 'q' received, quitting.\n\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("\t %c \t invalid token\n", c);
        }

        while ((strip = fgetc (src)) != '\n' && strip != EOF);
    }

    if (src && !stdf) fclose (src);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output - stdin**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_token_calc
 input :
            Blank Space
 input :
            Blank Space
 input : +
         +       addition operator
 input : -
         -       subtraction operator
 input : *
         *       multiplication operator
 input : /
         /       division operator
 input : ^
         ^       exponentiation
 input : (
         (       open parentheses
 input : )
         )       close parentheses
 input : <
         <       comparison operator
 input : >
         >       comparison operator
 input : <=
         <=      comparison equivalence operator
 input : >=
         >=      comparison equivalence operator
 input : 6
         6       simple numeral
 input : a
         a       invalid token
 input : q

 'q' received, quitting.
```

**Output - file**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_token_calc dat/tokens.txt
            Blank Space
            Blank Space
         +       addition operator
         -       subtraction operator
         *       multiplication operator
         /       division operator
         ^       exponentiation
         (       open parentheses
         )       close parentheses
         =       equals operator
         <       comparison operator
         >       comparison operator
         <=      comparison equivalence operator
         >=      comparison equivalence operator
         6       simple numeral

 'q' received, quitting.
```